# Elegant way to deal with a mix of important and non-important promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Given the following functions:

```
async function important(): Promise<any> {}
async function nonImportant(): Promise<any> {}
```

What is the best way to elegantly wait for all to be settled and throw only if the `important` promise fail ?

A few options I can think of

**Option 1:**

```
const [res,] = await Promise.allSettled([
 important(), nonImportant()
]);

if(res.status === "rejected"){
 throw res;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
await Promise.all([
 important(), 
 nonImportant().catch(e => return;)
])
```

**Option 3:**

Have my own helper function which takesan array of object with specifications on which one should throw:

```
await waitForAll([
 { promise: important(), shouldThrow: true },
 { promise: nonImportant(), shouldThrow: false }
]);
```

Which option would be the best or are there any better alternative ?

Comment: Option 2 seems like the best option, though I would probably change it to `catch(() => void 0)` or `catch(console.log)`. If you do end up using it multiple times you could go with a function (option 3), but I think a signature like `waitForAll(important: Array<Promise>, nonImportant: Array<Promise> = [])` would be easier to use.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the `Software Engineering` or `Code Review` stack exchange site.